Approximating the Lebesgue integral $\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ with step functions
I am trying to compute the following integral using Lebesgue by approximating with a step function but I feel that I am doing something wrong:
$\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$
Now I divide the range in the following way:
$\min{f(x)}=d_1<d_2.....<d_n<\max{f(x)}$
for any $k$ I take $d_i=\frac{i}{2^k}: i=1,...,k2^k$
Now $f^{-1}(d_i)=\frac{2^{2k}}{i^2}$ and
$f^{-1}(d_{i+1})=\frac{2^{2k}}{{(i+1)}^2}$
So the Lebesgue integral of the step function would be:
$\int_{[0,1]}s_ndm=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^n}(\frac{2^{2n}}{{(i+1)}^2}-\frac{2^{2n}}{i^2})$
This series doesn't appear to converge to the value of $2$ when you take $n$ to infinity

You should regard your step function as a collection of horizontal rectangles. The rectangles below the line $y=1$ form a square of area $1$, so it remains to consider the rectangles above the line $y=1$. At stage $n$ the rectangle between $y=d_i$ and $y=d_{i+1}$ has height $1/2^n$ and width $f^{-1}(d_{i+1})$ (since $f$ is decreasing) so the total area of these rectangles is
$$
\sum_{i=2^n}^{n2^n-1} \frac1{2^n}f^{-1}(d_{i+1})=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{i=2^n}^{n2^n-1}\frac{2^{2n}}{(i+1)^2}=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{i=2^n}^{n2^n-1}\frac1{((i+1)/2^n)^2}.
$$
Recognize this last as a Riemann sum for $\int_1^\infty\frac{dy}{y^2}$, which equals $1$.
Aside: To deal with the improper integral, you can obtain a "proper" Riemann sum by truncating at $i=M2^n-1$, so the truncated sum converges to $\int_1^M\frac{dy}{y^2}$. Then argue that the sum of the remaining terms can be made arbitrarily small as $n\to\infty$ by choosing $M$ large enough. One strategy is to bound the tail with a telescoping sum:
$$\frac1{2^n}\sum_{i=M2^n}^{n2^n-1}\frac1{((i+1)/2^n)^2}\le 2^n\sum_{i=M2^n}^\infty\frac1{i(i+1)}=2^n\sum_{i=M2^n}^\infty\left(\frac1i-\frac1{i+1}\right)=\frac1M
$$
